# Straight quotes only in contractions - want curly quotes - Windows 11, Word 2019

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

Word is set for curly quotes rather than straight quotes but it continues to put straight quotes in contracted words. It just started doing this recently. Why

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not happening here. Does it do this when you start Word in safe mode? https://support.office.com/article/dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean when you say Word is "set for curly quotes"?

Comment: @music2myear Word has an AutoFormat as you type option that substitutes right and left curly quotes and double quotes when the keyboard input is straight ones. See http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TameAutoFormat.htm.